# Get subset of rows in the numpy matrix based on the values from the column of another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

The title looks complicated, but the problem is not that hard. I have 2 matrices: `data_X` and `data_Y`. I have to construct a new matrix based on `data_X`, which will consists of all the rows of `data_X`, where the corresponding value in the column `column` in `data_Y` is not equal to `someNumber`. The same for `data_Y`. For example here is 5 by 2 `data_X` matrix and 5 by 1 `data_Y` matrix, `column` is 0 and `someNumber = -1`.

```
[[ 0.09580361  0.11221975]
 [ 0.71409124  0.24583188]
 [ 0.67346718  0.72550385]
 [ 0.40641294  0.01172211]
 [ 0.89974846  0.70378831]]  # data_X
```

and `data_Y = np.array([[5], [-1], [4], [2], [-1]])`.

The result would be:

```
[[ 0.09580361  0.11221975]
 [ 0.67346718  0.72550385]
 [ 0.40641294  0.01172211]]
[5 4 2]
```

It is not hard to see that this can be achieved by the following:

```
data_x, data_y = [], []
for i in xrange(len(data_Y)):
    if data_Y[i][column] != someNumber:
        data_y.append(data_Y[i][column])
        data_x.append(data_X[i])
```

But I believe there is way easier way (like 2 or 3 numpy operations) to get the results I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) -

```
In [228]: X
Out[228]: 
array([[ 0.09580361,  0.11221975],
       [ 0.71409124,  0.24583188],
       [ 0.67346718,  0.72550385],
       [ 0.40641294,  0.01172211],
       [ 0.89974846,  0.70378831]])

In [229]: Y
Out[229]: 
array([[ 5],
       [-1],
       [ 4],
       [ 2],
       [-1]])

In [230]: mask = Y!=-1 # Create mask for boolean indexing

In [231]: X[mask.ravel()]
Out[231]: 
array([[ 0.09580361,  0.11221975],
       [ 0.67346718,  0.72550385],
       [ 0.40641294,  0.01172211]])

In [232]: Y[mask]
Out[232]: array([5, 4, 2])
```